# Cannot catch android.intent.action.DELETE with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to register a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch an `Intent` with action `android.intent.action.DELETE` but I don't get anything.

Below you may find the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.UninstallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't get anything

`ACTION_DELETE` is used with `startActivity()`, not `sendBroadcast()`, so you cannot receive such `Intents` with a `BroadcastReceiver`.